# Usb_modeswitch doesnt seem to work in raspberry pi b+

Tags: raspbian, networking, usb, connection

I just purchased a raspberry pi b+. I want to connect to the internet using a 3g dongle (huawei ec152). I followed http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-setup-usb-3g-modem-raspberry-pi-using-usbmodeswitch-and-wvdial. It has worked on my raspberry pi B.

But now, I when I reach the line where I have to copy the data for usb modeswitch,I get no device found in archive.

I type this:

```
cd /tmp
tar -xzvf /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz 12d1\:140b
```

There is nothing found in the archive.

What to do ?

Just note, I am assuming that 140b was the DefaultProduct , and 1446 is target product

Comment: Why are you assuming 140b as the default product and 1446 as the target product? Have you actually checked them?

Comment: I am unsure about how to check them.

Answer (score 0):

so if you type `lsusb` you should get a list of devices one of which is your modem. The id is given in a xxxx:yyyy as vendor:device. That's what you can use to extract from the `configPack.tar.gz`.

If you do not have a device that matches your data first check the [official reference](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/device_reference.txt) to see if the device or one close to it is listed. if it is (but not yet in your configPack.tar.gz) you can add the entry you see in that reference to a file like `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/xxxx:yyyy`.

However, taking a look at the reference shows a device that has the id 12d1:1505 which is then automatically switched to 12d1:140b. In this case you can switch this step. To check see if you have a `/dev/gsmmodem` symlink. This means usb_modeswitch is already doing the switch for you and the device ID you saw in the output of lsusb is the switched one. (note that you can't just make up IDs)

The entry in this file (march 2016) is as follows:

```
########################################################
# Huawei EC156

DefaultVendor= 0x12d1
DefaultProduct=0x1505

TargetVendor=  0x12d1
TargetProduct= 0x140b

MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```

You can now just continue to your remaining steps to get the dialling working.